# Why does SQLite complain about the syntax of my prepared statement?

Tags: perl, sqlite, prepared-statement, syntax-error

I'm having trouble getting a prepared statement in sqlite3 to work. I'm working with Perl and the Perl DBD framework. Below is the code I use:

```
#This is a function I have defined
sub query($@){
    my $st = $db->prepare(shift);
    $st->execute(@_);
}

#And it is used like so
query("UPDATE rooms SET name = ?, SET capacity = ? WHERE id = ?", 
    $name, $capacity, $id);
```

When I try that, I get the following error:

```
DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: near "SET": syntax error(1) at dbdimp.c line 
271 at database.pm line 80.
```

Why do I get that error? If I try it without using prepared statements, it works. Every other prepared statement in my application works, except that UPDATE query.

Comment: It looks like you are using a name that consists of all lower case letters for your module. Don't do that as such names are reserved for pragmas. Besides, putting your modules in the top level namespace is bad practice anyway. You might end up naming one of your modules `Config.pm`.

Comment: When I have these sort of problems, I try the SQL statement directly in the database shell to see if its a problem with the statement or a problem with Perl.

Comment: I sat with this page in front of me, and I still couldn't figure out what was wrong! http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your query, using standard (and sqlite's) [UPDATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) syntax is

```
UPDATE rooms SET name = ?, capacity = ? WHERE id = ?
```

without a repeated SET